# Deadlock caused while creating a Thread in a static block in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I was just trying to create a Thread in a `static` block in Java that caused a deadlock to occur. The code snippet is as follows.

```
package deadlock;

final public class Main
{
    static int value;

    static
    {
        final Thread t = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                value = 1;
            }
        };

        t.start();
        System.out.println("Deadlock detected");

        try
        {
            t.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Released");
    }

    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        //Java stuff goes here.
    }
}
```

---

It just displays *Deadlock detected* on the console and hangs. I guess the reason for the deadlock to occur may be that the `static` block is loaded first before the `main()` method is invoked. Can you see the exact reason for the deadlock in the above code snippet?

Comment: Yes, the `static` block is executed before `main()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for the thread to be able to set the static value, the class must be loaded. In order for the class to be loaded, the thread must end (so that the static block completes). That's probably why you have a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

if you comment out

```
    try
    {
        t.join();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

deadlock will not occur...Your thread will run after class load.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you don't call this a deadlock. "Deadlock" implies that there is a monitor contention of some sort.

What you are doing has the same effect as calling

```
synchronized (Main.class) {
    try {
        Main.class.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

as the first thing in your main method. You are in a **wait state** from which you are never woken up.