# Multi-threaded code in a static initalizer block produces deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, static

I have a class that needs to provide a fast classification service.  For example, I want to write code like "classify("Ac Kd Kh 3c 3s")" that quickly returns TWO_PAIR.  (This isn't the application but you get the jist)

Because I need the classification to be quick I want to precompute, and then store, a look-up table that lists the classification output for all possible inputs.  In the interest of time I want to parallelize this precomputation.  HOWEVER, attempting to use "classifySlowly" from a 2nd thread creates a deadlock.

```
public class Classifcation Service {
  enum CLASS {TYPE_A, TYPE_B, ...};

  static CLASS[] preComputedClassLookUpTable;

  static {
    preComputedClassLookUpTable = constructLookUpTableInParallel();
  }

  //Note: using this method from with constructLookUpTableInParallel causes deadlock
  private static CLASS classifySlowly(Object classifyMe) {
    //do time intensive work to classify the input
    // -- uses no other methods from this class
    return classification;
  }

  public static CLASS classify(Object classifyMe) {
    //use the lookup table to do a quick classification
    return classification;
  }   
}
```

So my question is:  Is there a way to precompute this lookup table IN PARALLEL from within the static initalizer block?

The only (poor) alternative I see is to switch from:

```
preComputedClassLookUpTable = constructLookUpTableInParallel();
```

To:

```
preComputeClassLookUpTable = loadLookUpTableFromFile();
if(preComputedClassLookUpTable == null) {
  System.out.println("WARNING:  Construction incomplete, Must call computeAndSaveLookUpTableFile();}
}
```

---

I thought this would be too much but here is the implementation of constructLookUpTableInParallel

```
private static CLASS[] constructLookUpTableInParallel() {

  //build a collection of Runnables by iterating over all possible input Objects
  //wrap each possible input in an anonymous Runnable that calls classifySlowly.

  //submit the collection of Runnables to a new ExecutorService
  //process runnables...
  //shutdown executor service      
}
```

////////END OF POORLY WORDED ORIGINAL QUESTION ///////////

The solution that works somewhat cleanly is splitting the classifySlowly(Object classifyMe) and classify(Object classifyMe) methods into two different classes.

This will allow the (first) class that contains "public static CLASS classifySlowly(Object classifyMe)" to be fully loaded by the time the (second) class that contains "public static CLASS classifyQuickly(Object classifyMe)" needs to use the classifySlowly method.  Now, that the 2nd static inialization block don't require any of its own static methods it can be fully parallelized.

Comment: It is pretty hard to debug multi-threaded code when you don't post the multi-threaded code. What is `constructLookUpTableInParallel` doing?

Comment: How do you know its a deadlock? Why is `loadLookUpTableFromFile` poor alternative? It may be a good idea to precompute and store in a file for even faster initialization

Comment: @JohnB -- it's hiding that complexity.  If constructLookUpTableInParallel started no new threads the program would work fine.  However, if you must know, it creates a set of Runnables to do each classification task and then submits those Runnables to an ExecutorService

Comment: How can it deadlock when there is no synchronized blocks or other locking?

Comment: Good luck getting an answer if you are "hiding" all the pertinent details

Comment: @MV -- (1) It becomes a deadlock because the threads launched in the parallelizing method want access to the classifySlowly method (which they can't have because the class isn't fully loaded yet).  (2)  loadLookUpTableFromFile is bad because I want to automate the construction of the lookUpTable if it isn't found.  I don't want to only print a warning

Comment: @JohnB -- I'm just trying to balance between spamming code and over simplifying the problem.

Comment: @hyde -- The problem is that the thread that execute the static initalizer is the only thread that has access to static methods until AFTER then static initalizer block is completed.  Here is a similar thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610369/deadlock-caused-while-creating-a-thread-in-a-static-block-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"So my question is: Is there a way to precompute this lookup table IN PARALLEL from within the static initalizer block?"

Yes, it's practically certain there is a way. Just new the array and launch a Runnable for each array element. Give each Runnable reference to the array, and index it is computing, then have it do the computing without locking, then lock when assigning result to the array element.

Note/disclaimer: this answer is based on the rather incomplete information given in the question...

Comment: I tried something very similar, it doesn't work because the runnables can't access classifySlowly until AFTER the static initalizer block has been completed.

Comment: So, change order or split up static initializer blocks, or even split it to multiple classes. Why does classifySlowly need to be in that same class?

Comment: I hoped to have everything in the same class for simplicity.  I'll try having 2 different static initalizer blocks with this solution...but I think I already tried it.

Comment: Speaking generally, and as a personal opinion, especially in Java language (with plenty of enums, inner classes, anonymous classes...), trying too hard to keep things in one class is not a good habit. When things stop fitting inside one class, refactor! When a package has too many files, move stuff to subpackages! Java IDEs make that fairly painless, too.